# Connection Strings for SQL Server 2014 (one works, one doesn't)

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

Can someone explain why I can't connect to my local machine SQL Server with this string...

````
sDSN = "driver={SQL Server};server=WMI-J9FJ8Z1\SQLEXPRESS2014;uid=sa;pwd=ghbyn;database=mtls4ushop"```
````

But this string works (I took it from my UDL file I used for testing)

````
sDSN = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=ghbyn;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=mtls4ushop;Data Source=WMI-J9FJ8Z1\EXPRESS2014"```
````

It works, but LOCALHOST running very slowly and I'm in a time crunch for this project created because of the Covid-19.

My environment is IIS 6.1 with SQL Server 2014

I have another website on this same server, that is using the identically formatted string, and it works fine, and fast.

Comment: Add the code you are using to connect.  In particular, what client driver and library are you using?  ADO.NET, ADO, ODBC, ...

Comment: David, I haven't a clue....